# Algebra question: Finding inverse function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

This question is about finding the inverse function of $f(x)=-\sqrt{9-x^2}$

I seem to be making an error with one of the manipulations. Here is my attempt.

$$x=-\sqrt{9-y^2}$$
$$x^2=(-\sqrt{9-y^2})^2$$
$$x^2= -(9-y^2)$$
$$x^2=y^2-9$$
$$x^2+9=y^2$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+9}=\sqrt{y^2}$$
$$y=\sqrt{x^2+9}$$

The answer is $f^{-1} (x)=-\sqrt{9-x^2},-3≤x ≤0$

In which step did I make a mistake?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
y=-\sqrt{9-x^2}
\end{align}
Change $x$ to $y$ and vice versa.
\begin{align}
x&=-\sqrt{9-y^2}\\
-x&=\sqrt{9-y^2}\\
(-x)^2&=\left(\sqrt{9-y^2}\right)^2\\
x^2&=9-y^2\\
y^2&=9-x^2\\
y&=\pm\sqrt{9-x^2}
\end{align}
The last step, change $y$ to $f^{-1}(x)$.
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(x)&=\pm\sqrt{9-x^2}
\end{align}
Since there is a symmetry between a function and its inverse. Specifically, if $f(x)$ is an invertible function with domain $x$ and range $y$, then its inverse $f^{-1}(x)$ has domain $y$ and range $x$. Therefore, the inverse function of $f(x)=-\sqrt{9-x^2}$ is
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(x)&=-\sqrt{9-x^2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

The 3rd line is wrong. It should be: $x^2 = 9 - y^2$, and you can take care of the remaining steps.

Comment: @glacier: did you read his question?

Comment: Ok, from the third line as $x^2=9-y^2$ I end up with $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$ Where does the negative sign in front of the radical come from?

Comment: Both $y = \sqrt{9 - x^2}$ and $y = -\sqrt{9 - x^2}$ gives $9 - x^2$ when squared, so you will have to consider both of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't square a negative term and preserve the sign (third step)